# Opera Prefers Flash over HTML5 on Youtube

Tags: video, flash, youtube, html5, opera

**System:** Xubuntu 14.04.3
**Browser:** Opera 33.0.1990.43

I installed Flash using [this way](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/12/how-to-get-flash-and-h264-to-work-in.html).

I'm okay with Flash. However, whenever I open up a Youtube video, HTML5 player is blocked by Flash. Then it does not change to Flash player in the first attempt and stays like below:

[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odnnD.png)

I reload the page, sometimes it changes to Flash player in the second attempt if I'm lucky, but I usually need to reload page a couple of times.

This is a nightmare if the player is *embedded*. It does not even change to Flash player if it's not embedded.

So, is there a way to:

- keep HTML5 player where it is available or...
- completely change to Flash player, even in embedded ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was wandering around Opera extensions. So I found [this extension](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/flash-player-for-youtubetm/?display=en) to get over this issue. It simply forces Opera to use Flash over HTML5 player and works in embedded players.

I wanted to answer as a solution just in case. If there appears another solution for HTML5 player, I'll try that with pleasure.

Comment: Since there's no further answer for a week, I choose this as valid answer.